# How to keep cookies values saved in angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cookies, session-cookies

I save this cookies in the app component like this:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  item=new Array();

  constructor(private Cookies:CookieService){
  this.Cookies.set('dislikedShops',${this.item});

  //I am trying to use localStorage but the same as the cookie service
  // localStorage.setItem('dislikedShops',${['Shop1']});
}

ngOnInit() {
}

onShopLiked(shopTitle: String) {
  // this.item = [${localStorage.getItem('dislikedShops')}];
  this.item =new Array(${this.cookieService.get('dislikedShops')});

  //Append New Shop Item to localStorage list
  this.item.push(shopTitle);
  this.cookieService.set('dislikedShops',${this.item});

  //Get shop Details and add it with preferred shops
  console.log(this.cookieService.get('dislikedShops'));
}
```

When I reload the page all cookies values are lost. Is there anyway to keep these values on the browsers and control it by time. This cookie here in the app component it's just for the initialization, and after that I have a main page which has a list of cards contain two buttons like/dislike, when the user press to dislike button it will be append new title value of the cards in this cookie.

So the problem is when I reload the page the cookie had lost all values?

Comment: Did you write this in accordance with the directives? Provide as you add. because there is no error. Is there any error output?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Comment: You need to either tell us the library you're using for `CookieService` or post the code for the `CookieService`. Otherwise, all answers are just a guess.

Comment: I have edited this question please see the details?